# Sending triggers to client using websockets in spring boot and angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I want to initiate a trigger(maybe a notification) from backend(based in spring boot) to a particular user whose userId is xyz.

the one way i have found is:

initially i connect to a websocket end point and subscribe to channel "/user/Notifications/xyz"
following is the relevant code in my angular typescript

```
connectToUserWebSocket(userId) {
        let socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:5000/fellowGenius');
        this.ws = Stomp.over(socket);
        let that = this;
        this.ws.connect(
          {},
          (frame) => {
            that.ws.subscribe('/user/Notifications/' +userId, (message) => {
            console.log("user subscribed");
            });
    
          },
          (error) => {
            alert('STOMP error ' + error);
          }
        );
        
    }
```

Now once i have subscribed to my channel . I want to send a trigger to client which is initiated by backend itself so i run a code in my java service.
My relevant java code is:

```
@SendTo("/user/Notifications/{userId}")
    public String sendMeetingNotificationWebSocket(@DestinationVariable String userId) {
        return "hello";
    }
```

my websocket configurations are:

```
@Configuration      
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/fellowGenius").setAllowedOrigins("*").addInterceptors(new HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor()).withSockJS();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/inbox/","/user/Notifications/");
        }
}
```

But the problem is that even i can see one web socket connected in my spring boot console.
But i don't get a response from the function on the client side.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: you dont just get user subscribed multiple times in console ?

Comment: i didn't get your question